# Merge into CTE vs Merge into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question regarding performance of *Merge into CTE* against *Merge into Table*.

My scenario is as below:

I am facing an issue in existing stored procedure which is responsible to merge data into table from staging source table. The target table has around 20 million records.
Merging is performed into **CTE** which is subset of target table filtered on date range. This date range matches with the date range of source table. However, due to incorrect logic implementation, the source table sometimes contain data out of the date range as well. This results in unwanted & duplicate data insertion into target table.

The logic in the stored procedure is now corrected and this change is expected to fix the issue. But, to be sure that, such kind of issue never occur again, is it advisable to merge into table instead of CTE? Considering the size of the target table (~20M rows), what will be the performance trade-off? What are the pros and cons to merge into table considering performance point of view?

Comment: To be honest, it's better to avoid the merge statement altogether whenever it gets  complex, for both readability and performance. You can split the merge with an insert, update and/or delete depending on your current operations, just make sure that you do it on a transaction so it's consistent.

Comment: @EzLo, yes, I agree with you. However, I would like to understand the performance overhead and also the scenarios when to go for Merge into table and Merge into CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft advises against using CTEs as targets.

> Use the WITH  clause to filter out rows from
>   the source or target tables. This method is similar to specifying
>   additional search criteria in the ON clause and may produce incorrect
>   results. We recommend that you avoid using this method or test
>   thoroughly before implementing it.

See for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#join-best-practices

From performance standpoint I do not think it would make any difference. I have never tested this though.

Comment: How does SQL Server "know" how each row in a CTE maps to the source table row? and what if the CTE has computed-columns or JOIN expressions? There's a lot of voodoo around writing to CTEs that I feel is underdocumented.

Comment: @Dai , I do not know for sure, but I would imagine it is the same way as writing into an [Uptable View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views).